# Linux scription to export variable from parameter file

Tags: linux, scripting, export

In a shell script, I am using the following command to execute a parameter file; I want to export all the variables from that parameter file. It's working in dev and when I migrated to UAT it fails with error  ": command not found"

Main script has following content .  I am passing `BaseDir` path as the parameter (here it is `/usr/test/proj`)

### Main script:

```
#!/bin/sh
BaseDir=$1

. ${BaseDir}/test.prm

export TEST1
export TEST2
```

### test.prm

```
TEST1=/usr/test/home  
TEST2=12345
```

I tried to do a command line execution also:

```
. /usr/test/proj/test.prm
```

This was successful in my dev environment, but failing in UAT.  Both servers are on Linux.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what exactly fails? any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

First mainscript.sh chmod +x, chmod 777 /home/script/mainscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$(dirname "$0")"
. $dir/functions/settings.sh
settings
echo $GODADDY_API_URL
echo $GODADDY_CSV_FILE
echo $GODADDY_CSV_FILE_DETAILED
echo $GODADDY_API_KEY
```

Functions file settings.sh chmod +x, chmod 777 /home/script/functions/script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$(dirname "$0")"
SETTINGS="$dir/data/settings.list"
function settings {
    . $SETTINGS
}
```

Settings file settings.list chmod +x, chmod 777 /home/script/data/settings.list

```
GODADDY_API_URL=https://api.godaddy.com
GODADDY_CSV_FILE="All domains.csv"
GODADDY_CSV_FILE_DETAILED="All domains detailed.csv"
GODADDY_API_KEY=1qazxsw23edcvfr45tgb
```

Comment: . /path/to/param.file  - This line is failing

Comment: For tests try to chmod +x, chmod 777 /parameters/file

Comment: Itsa failing.  I tried to do it from the fiolder where prm file resides, but no luck                                                                                             [usr@server ]$ . param.prm
: command not found
[usr@server ]$

Comment: take a look, I changed my answer to one of my working scripts to work with godaddy api.

Comment: This is resolved. Actually folder where the paramter file located is created with sticky bit and was not allowing to execute anything there changed the permission and is working now